# Unity: Possible to call Game Event from OnTriggerEnter?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm attempting to call Game Event from an OnTriggerEvent method, but it's not working. I'm not seeing documentation on this, or else it's not clear to me from the [Order of Execution](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html) chart, but it seems that OnTriggerEvent hides event passing.

I have a player object and a checkpoint object that have collider triggers. When the player  collides with the checkpoint, the Checkpoint.cs script should fire a game event when the player enters.

Checkpoint.cs:

```
    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider hitObject) {

        GameEvents.current.CheckpointReached(this);

}
```

The GameEvent.cs script:

```
public class GameEvents : MonoBehaviour
{
    
public event Action<Checkpoint> OnCheckpointReached;


public void CheckpointReached(Checkpoint checkpoint)
    {
        if (OnCheckpointReached != null)
        {
            Debug.Log("Checkpoint reached!");
            OnCheckpointReached(checkpoint);

        }


    }
}
```

Other methods called from OnTriggerEnter are working fine, so it doesn't seem to be a collider issue, and Game Events do work for other objects in the scene.

Comment: Add a log before `GameEvents.current.CheckpointReached(this)` to check if this is reached at all ;)

Comment: Also what if `OnCheckpointReached == null` ? In that case you also just do nothing so also add a log there just for confirming now

Comment: In order for two trigger colliders to emit an OnTriggerEnter event, at least one of the objects needs to have a rigidbody. Make sure your two objects meet the requirements shown in the [Unity documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/2021.1/Documentation/Manual/CollidersOverview.html).

Comment: Thanks, the checkpoint object does not have a rigidbody, so I think that's the issue.